# Can't resolve all parameters for BsModalService

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-modal

I'm adding a modal to my spfx angular 2 application. I was trying to follow `ngx-bootstrap-modal` through http://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals. but I am getting this error:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Can't resolve all parameters for AppComponent: (?). ; Zone: <root> ; Task:
```

This is what my code looks like:

package.json

```
{
  "name": "our-applications",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.4.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.4",
    "@angular/core": "^2.4.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.4",
    "@angular/http": "^2.4.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.4",
    "@angular/router": "^3.4.4",
    "@angular/upgrade": "^2.4.4",
    "@microsoft/sp-client-base": "~1.0.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-client-preview": "~1.0.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-core-library": "~1.0.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base": "~1.0.0",
    "@types/webpack-env": ">=1.12.1 <1.14.0",
    "angular2-modal": "^3.0.1",
    "ng2-modal": "0.0.25",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^1.8.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.9",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.3",
    "sp-pnp-js": "^2.0.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@microsoft/sp-build-web": "~1.0.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-module-interfaces": "~1.0.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-workbench": "~1.0.0",
    "@types/chai": "^>=3.4.34 <3.6.0",
    "@types/mocha": ">=2.2.33 <2.6.0",
    "gulp": "~3.9.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gulp bundle",
    "clean": "gulp clean",
    "test": "gulp test"
  }
}
```

my html that calls the function:

```
 <button (click)="addApp();" class="ms-Button ms-Button--primary">
            <span class="ms-Button-label">Add Application</span>
        </button>
```

snippet of my app.component.js

```
import { Component, OnInit,ViewEncapsulation, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { AppSettings } from './shared/app.settings';
import { IApplicationEntity } from './shared/app.entities';
import { BsModalService } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal/modal-options.class';

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    bsModalRef: BsModalRef;

    constructor(private modalService: BsModalService) {}

    public addApp() {
        console.log("open the modal");
        let list = ['Open a modal with component', 'Pass your data', 'Do something else', '...'];
        this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(ModalContentComponent);
        this.bsModalRef.content.title = 'Modal with component';
        this.bsModalRef.content.list = list;
    }
}
```

and this is my app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ModalModule } from 'angular2-modal';
import { BootstrapModalModule } from 'angular2-modal/plugins/bootstrap';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppSettings } from './shared/app.settings';
import { AppLoadingComponent } from './shared/loading/app.loading';
import { AppNotifyComponent } from './shared/notify/app.notify';
import { BsModalService } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';


@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule 
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent, 
        AppLoadingComponent,
        AppNotifyComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})

export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: are you using system.config?

Comment: hi @Sajeetharan no, my application do not have system.config. Apologies i'm actually new to angular js.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From your `app.module.ts`, you didn't add `ModalModule` to `imports array`, the solution should be import `ModalModule` from `ngx-bootstrap` and add it to your imports array.

```
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
// or
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';

imports: [BrowserModule, ModalModule.forRoot()],
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   mention here
```

Refer **[Plunker DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/THjbu6JZMKgGMJM1gInl?p=preview)**.

Seems a late answer but hope it'll help solve your problem.

Comment: YES, Solved. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Posting this as it might help someone.

If you have created different NgModules in your app, Don't forget to import `ModalModule` in those modules too.

```
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';

@NgModule({
  imports: [    
    ModalModule.forRoot()    
  ],
  declarations: [
    ExampleComponent,    
  ],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
})
export class ExampleModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

From quick glance of your code I notice that you have ES6 import statement for BSModalService in your AppModule but it is not imported into your angular AppModule. Please add BSModalService into AppModule imports as shown below.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ModalModule } from 'angular2-modal';
import { BootstrapModalModule } from 'angular2-modal/plugins/bootstrap';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppSettings } from './shared/app.settings';
import { AppLoadingComponent } from './shared/loading/app.loading';
import { AppNotifyComponent } from './shared/notify/app.notify';
import { BsModalService } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';


@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, BsModalService 
],
declarations: [
    AppComponent, 
    AppLoadingComponent,
    AppNotifyComponent],
bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})

export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Hi Bala,when i added it in the import i got this error: 
 [SPWebPartErrorCode.ScriptLoadError]:: Unable to load web part WebPart.OurApplicationsWebPart.dba29c21-45f3-4bbe-ab5e-6e0bc375f378,Error: ***Failed to load component "0a847cdc-0309-4af4-a025-d084e8e66554" (OurApplicationsWebPart). Original error: ***Failed to load entry point from component "0a847cdc-0309-4af4-a025-d084e8e66554" (OurApplicationsWebPart). script resources due to: {1}. CALLSTACK:: Error at SPWebPartError.SPError [as constructor]