# No provider error inside Angular library project

Tags: angular

This is a odd one.

I have a simple library called, let's say, layout.

This library has a simple module called LayoutModule. Inside LayoutModule we have a HeaderComponent declared.

Inside HeaderComponent we have a dependency to the BsModalService from the ngx-bootstrap library which is a dependency of my layout library.

It looks like this:

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        HeaderComponent
    ],

    imports: [
        ModalModule
    ],
    exports: [
        HeaderComponent
    ],
    providers: []
})
export class LayoutModule {}
```

Everything gets builded, packed and deployed to the npm registry. So far, so good.

But when other applications install it, we get the:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[HeaderComponent -> BsModalService]:
```

This error tells me that there is no provider for the BsModalService, which is odd, because it is imported both in the LayoutModule and in the AppModule as:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        LayoutModule,
        ModalModule.forRoot()
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I've tried a lot of things so far like using the .forRoot() method inside the LayoutModule, deleting the node_modules folder, deleting the package-lock.json. Also tried to build over and over again, but it's no use.

It does not work and I don't understand why. Any ideas?

Edit:

I've forgot to mention that it works when I use ng serve, but it breaks when I use the ng serve --aot. The --aot flag is important because it emulates the production build.

The scenario is:

Application ABC installs library layout + ng serve = works!

Application ABC installs library layout + ng serve --aot = fails!

Answer (score 0):

[Can't resolve all parameters for BsModalService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45704518/cant-resolve-all-parameters-for-bsmodalservice)

looks like you need to add `ModalModule.forRoot()`

Comment: Yep. Tried that. Didn't work either. I think is something within the build process, but I don't know what. It should work, but it doesn't. Building with production mode or just using the --aot flag, breaks with the no provider error. It works when builded in development though.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem was in the package.json and in how the dependencies were set.

The library dependency to ngx-bootstrap was set in dependencies attribute instead of peerDependencies. That was causing intermitent errors through out the applications that used the library.

So what I did was change this:

```
{
    "name": "my-layout",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "author": "Myself",
    "peerDependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "~8.0.1",
        "@angular/core": "~8.0.1"
    },
    "dependencies" : {
        "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.1.1",
    }
}
```

To this:

```
{
    "name": "my-layout",
    "version": "1.0.0",
     "author": "Myself",
     "peerDependencies": {
         "@angular/common": "~8.0.1",
         "@angular/core": "~8.0.1",
         "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.1.1",
     }
}
```

And worked.

Well, at least I suppose that this was the cause.